# Why would a malicious declaration of Rosh Hachodesh be legal (R"H 25a)?

Tags: beit-din-court, rosh-chodesh-new-month, maseches-rosh-hashana

R' Akiva famously interpreted a verse to legalize malicious rulings of Kiddush Hachodesh:

> "אתם אפילו שוגגין אתם אפילו **מזידין** אתם אפילו מוטעין:"
> "[You are authorized to determine the date of the new month], even unwittingly/by miscalculation; you, even maliciously; you, even misled by false witnesses". [Rosh_Hashanah.25a](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.25a.14?lang=bi&with=Ritva&lang2=en)

Some translate "מזידין" as merely intentional (neutral), but this is a wrong translation, as in Hebrew זדון can only mean an evil, corrupted intention, against the existing Law, as it always appears in the Tanach or Mishnah:

> "ותתן אתת ומפתים בפרעה ובכל־עבדיו ובכל־עם ארצו כי ידעת כי הזידו עליהם" (Neh 9:10)
> "וְהָאִישׁ אֲשֶׁר־יַעֲשֶׂה בְזָדוֹן לְבִלְתִּי שְׁמֹעַ אֶל־הַכֹּהֵן" Deut 17:12
> "אֲנִי יָדַעְתִּי אֶת־זְדֹנְךָ וְאֵת רֹעַ לְבָבֶךָ" I Sam 17:28
> "אָדָם מוּעָד לְעוֹלָם, בֵּין שׁוֹגֵג, בֵּין מֵזִיד, בֵּין עֵר, בֵּין יָשֵׁן." B"K 2:6

See [Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%96%D6%B8%D7%93%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%9F.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): "זָדוֹן m. (b. h.; זוד) *premeditated, conscious sin*"

Why would a malicious declaration of Rosh Hachodesh be legal? What's the logic behind it, and wouldn't it promote corruption and exploitation, just like what the Saducees demanded?

Comment: That's what the Gezeiras Hakasuv is. אתם אפילו מזידין .

Comment: If a kohen deliberately (maizid) had a thought of pigul when bringing a korban, why should it make the korban passul? Once you have a power to do something from the Torah, it doesn't make a difference if your maizid or not.

Comment: I'm not convinced meizid must mean malicious

Answer (score 5):

The Rambam in Hilchos Kiddush Hachodesh Perek 2, leaves out the option of Meizid, however Tosfos on 22B clearly says that he had the words included in the Gemarah.

[The Yaavitz](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37956&st=&pgnum=173) in his commentary to Rosh Hashana cites his commentary on Avos 3:13, where he qualifies that there's no disagreement between them. Tosfos' meizid means with a reason but it's called meizid because it's done with intention. Whereas the Rambam is referring to a meizid with malicious intent which, he says, wouldn't be valid according to anyone.

Comment: Well done! So Rambam says it wouldn't be legal and leaves it out - nice!